# minimum penalty path in weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

Consider an undirected graph containing *N* nodes and *M* edges. Each edge *M<sub>i</sub>* has an integer cost, *C<sub>i</sub>*, associated with it.

The penalty of a path is the bitwise OR of every edge cost in the path between a pair of nodes, *A* and *B*. In other words, if a path contains edges *M<sub>1</sub>*,*M<sub>2</sub>*,...,*M<sub>k</sub>* then the penalty for this path is *C<sub>1</sub>* OR *C<sub>2</sub>* OR ... OR *C<sub>k</sub>*.

Given a graph and two nodes, *A* and *B*, find the path between *A* and *B* having the minimal possible penalty and print its penalty; if no such path exists, print `−1` to indicate that there is no path from *A* to *B*.

Note: **Loops and multiple edges are allowed.**

constraints:

1≤*N*≤10<sup>3</sup>

1≤*M*≤10<sup>3</sup>

1≤*C<sub>i</sub>*<1024

1≤*U<sub>i</sub>*,*V<sub>i</sub>*≤*N*

1≤*A*,*B*≤*N*

*A*≠*B*

this question is asked in a contest and its over I went through the tutorial but could not get it. can anyone explain or give the answer how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved using Dynamic programming by following the recursive formula:

```
D(s,0) = true
D(v,i) = false OR D(v,i) OR { D(u,j) | (u,v) is an edge, j or c(u,v) = i }
```

Where `s` is the source node.

The idea is `D(v,i) == true` if and only if there is a path from `s` to `v` with weight of exactly `i`.

Now, you iteratively modify the graph in your dynamic programming, until it converges (which is at most after `n` iterations).

This is basically a variant of [Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).
When you are done creating the DP table for the solution, the minimal path is `min { x | D(t,x) = true}` (where `t` is the target node).

Time complexity is `O(m*n*log_2(R))`, where `R` is the maximal weight allowed (1024 in your case).

Comment: can you elaborate it.

Comment: @rj124 I added some clarification, hope it is clear.

Comment: can't it be done with dijkstra algorithm? while relaxing the edge we can compute the `|`of path distance till now with the current edge weight and insert it into the min priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Rather than adding the weight for each node, you should be ORing it.

So, the pseudo-code would be as follows (modified from the wikipedia example):

```
 1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3      create vertex set Q
 4
 5      for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
 6          dist[v] ← INFINITY                  // Unknown distance from source to v
 7          prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                 // Previous node in optimal path from source
 8          add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
 9
10      dist[source] ← 0                        // Distance from source to source
11      
12      while Q is not empty:
13          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Source node will be selected first
14          remove u from Q 
15          
16          for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
17              alt ← dist[u] OR length(u, v)
18              if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
19                  dist[v] ← alt 
20                  prev[v] ← u 
21
22      return dist[], prev[]
```

Note the OR on line 17.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
typedef pair <ll,ll > pr;
vector <pr> adj[10005];
bool visited[10005][10005];
int main(){
    ll n,m;
    scanf("%lld%lld",&n,&m);
    for(ll i=1;i<=m;i++){
        ll u,v,w;
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&u,&v,&w);
        adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v,w));
        adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u,w));
    }
    ll source,destination;
    scanf("%lld%lld",&source,&destination);
    queue<ll> bfsq;
    bfsq.push(source);// source into queue
    bfsq.push(0);// 
    while(!bfsq.empty()){
    ll u=bfsq.front();
        bfsq.pop();
        ll cost=bfsq.front();
        bfsq.pop();
        visited[u][cost]=true;
        for(ll i=0;i<adj[u].size();i++){
          ll  v=adj[u][i].first;// neighbor of u is v
          ll  w2=adj[u][i].second;//// u is connected to v with this cost
          if(visited[v][w2|cost]==false){
            visited[v][w2|cost]=true;
            bfsq.push(v);
            bfsq.push(w2|cost);


          }
        }
    }
    ll ans=-1LL;
    for(ll i=0;i<1024;i++){
        if(visited[destination][i]==true){
            ans=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%lld\n",ans);
    return 0;

}
```